# FOP 2.2 RTF Export | Table header text | Bottom to top alignment not working

Tags: pdf-generation, rtf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using fop 2.2 and below mentioned xml for generating the table. 
[image]

It produces correct pdf documents, see below 
[image]

but in rtf export, the text don't get vertical and inverted as well.

[image]
 Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

FOP RTF support is very limited. Per the FOP website:

"JFOR, an open source XSL-FO to RTF converter has been integrated into Apache FOP. This will create an RTF (rich text format) document that will attempt to contain as much information from the XSL-FO document as possible. It should be noted that is not possible (due to RTF's limitations) to map all XSL-FO features to RTF. For complex documents, the RTF output will never reach the feature level from PDF, for example. Thus, using RTF output is only recommended for simple documents such as letters."

It is highly likely it is not supported. Since your test is valid that it produces PDF fine but not RTF, it is most likely the fact that it is not supported in FOP RTF output.